# Swiping not working with navigation controller

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I'm new in IOS development and using plainly on storyboard as a start. I have the Navigation controller linked to my main viewcontroller. I create a button and add a Push segue that link to an info1 viewcontroller. Inside I add a UIImageView to display an image. Then I add a Swipe Gesture Recognizer within the info1 viewcontroller to swipe to info2 viewcontroller.

So far, the button push to info1 viewcontroller works. But the swipe to info2 viewcontroller is not working.

Any hints how I can rectify this problem?

I tried removing the UIImageView may not help but still not recognizing the swipe. I didn't add any codes. Just using storyboard with navigation controller.

Thanks

Comment: You need to give more information on what exactly you did to set up the storyboard. This should work if you have it set up right.

Comment: have you implemented the gesture recognizer delegate methods?

Comment: @rdelmar I managed to get it working by deleting everything in storyboards and re-create them. I still dunno what happens before that. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @calvinBhai I do not implementing anything in codes yet. Just purely using navigation controllers, viewcontrollers and segue.

Comment: I'll need to know what "working" and "not working" means. Guessing: Control click on the gestureRecognizer on the left bar, and drag to the info2 view controller. You should see options to make it push/modal/custom action on receiving a swipe. Make sure you have set the swipe direction (click on the recognizer on the left, you'll see options to set the direction in the inspector on the right).